# Can I send a SelectList through the UIHint Control Parameters?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, data-annotations, selectlist, mvc-editor-templates

Can I send a SelectList through a Data Annotation? Something like...

```
[UIHint("DropDownList", "", new SelectList(new[] {"one","two","three"}))]
public virtual int? OptionID { get; set; }
```

I don't understand the syntax but this seems possible. If so, how do I access it from an editor template?

If not, how could I dynamically send a SelectList to a DropDownList Editor Template? I specifically would like to avoid making a separate template for every SelectList - I have too many of them. Thanks

**EDIT:** I'm working on the second option (Reflection) because I thought it might be more direct than overriding that 15-syllable monster, the DataAnnotationsModelMetadataProvider.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to take a look at this blog post:

http://mikevdm.com/BlogEntry/Key/Using-UIHint-With-ControlParameters-in-MVC

Here's a relevant quote:

> ControlParameters are limited in that they can only accept (compile-time) constant values, in a somewhat unusual syntax, but they do allow simple vales (true/false, enumerated values, etc.), so your templated helper can behave slightly differently based on parameters. This allows you to combine related functionality, usually found in individual templates (with lots of code duplication), into one single template.

In my app, all my drop down lists were either nullable bools (Yes, No, not set) or enums. I took the route of making a separate template for each one, but using helper methods to make the code within each template very minimal.

For example, I have a template called Level (where `Level` is an enum):

The code is just a couple usings plus....

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model, Model.ToSelectList<Level>())
```

I use these extension methods for `ToSelectList`:

```
public static SelectList ToSelectList<TEnum>(this TEnum? value) where TEnum : struct
{
    var items = GetSelectListItems<TEnum>().ToList();
    items.Insert(0, new SelectListItem { Value = "", Text = LabelIfNull });
    return new SelectList(items, "Value", "Text", value.ToString());
}

public static SelectList ToSelectList<TEnum>(this TEnum value)
{
    var items = GetSelectListItems<TEnum>();
    return new SelectList(items, "Value", "Text", value.ToString());
}

public static IEnumerable<SelectListItem> GetSelectListItems<TEnum>()
{
    var values = System.Enum.GetNames(typeof(TEnum));
    return values.Select(v => new SelectListItem { Value = v, Text = v.ToFriendlyName() });
}

public static SelectList ToSelectList(this bool isTrue)
{
    var items = new[]
    {
        new SelectListItem { Value = "true", Text = LabelIfTrue },
        new SelectListItem { Value = "false", Text = LabelIfFalse }
    };
    return new SelectList(items, "Value", "Text", isTrue.ToString());
}

public static SelectList ToSelectList(this bool? isTrue)
{
    var items = new[]
    {
        new SelectListItem { Value = string.Empty, Text = LabelIfNull },
        new SelectListItem { Value = "true", Text = LabelIfTrue },
        new SelectListItem { Value = "false", Text = LabelIfFalse }
    };
    return new SelectList(items, "Value", "Text", !isTrue.HasValue ? string.Empty : isTrue.Value.ToString());
}
```

Perhaps you could use control parameters to get down to a single template, but you'll definitely need to write your own `DataAnnotationsModelMetadataProvider`, as indicated in the blog post.

Comment: thanks for your reply! I did see that blog post before. The extension method thing is a little over my newbie head, but I will try to understand it. What if I skip the annotations and the custom MDP - do you think there is a way to use reflection in an overridden object template to send a selectlist to the dropdown template? Should I make that a separate question? Thanks again.

Comment: I should add that though I had seen that blog post, I definitely did not catch the relevant quote until you pointed it out, so thanks for that :)

Comment: These `ToSelectList()` methods simply allow you to say `model.ToSelectList()` instead of `GetSelectList(model)`. It's just "syntactic sugar" that makes it look like these methods are part of the class. LINQ works this way.

Comment: It shouldn't be too difficult to write a `ToSelectList()` method for an EF4.1 dbset. The one tricky part is that you will need to know the fields to use to map to the `Value` and `Text` properties of the SelectList. If you are always mapping say `Id` and `Name` for each table, you may want to create an interface that all your entity objects implement that has `Id` and `Name` as properties. If the fields are not always the same, I'm pretty sure you'll need to include the field names as control parameters and use reflection.

Comment: Link http://mikevdm.com/BlogEntry/Key/Using-UIHint-With-ControlParameters-in-MVC requires a login.